# Create calendar event using Microsoft Graph Client

Tags: javascript, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I'm trying to figure out how to create a calendar event using the Microsoft Graph JavaScript Client.

I've managed to retrieve the necessary `accessToken` and can interact with the API (i.e. retrieve events, calendars, top 10 e-mails), but I'm not sure of how to use the API to create an event.

```js
client
    .api('/me/events')
    .header('X-AnchorMailbox', emailAddress)
```

Do I use post to send the event json object?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I suggest reviewing the [Read Medocumentation](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-javascript#post-and-patch) for details on how to use this library.

To answer your question, you need to create a an [Event](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/event) object. For example:

```js
var event = {
    "subject": "Let's go for lunch",
    "body": {
        "contentType": "HTML",
        "content": "Does late morning work for you?"
    },
    "start": {
        "dateTime": "2017-04-15T12:00:00",
        "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
    },
    "end": {
        "dateTime": "2017-04-15T14:00:00",
        "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
    },
    "location": {
        "displayName": "Harry's Bar"
    },
    "attendees": [{
        "emailAddress": {
            "address": "samanthab@contoso.onmicrosoft.com",
            "name": "Samantha Booth"
        },
        "type": "required"
    }]
}
```

You then need to `.post` this object to the `/events` endpoint:

```js
client
    .api('/me/events')
    .post(event, (err, res) => {
        console.log(res)
    })
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you Marc

Comment: Thank you so much! Beside that, i want to append single-value property for this event. I added more body based on this link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/singlevaluelegacyextendedproperty-post-singlevalueextendedproperties?view=graph-rest-1.0 but it does not working.
My question is here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/singlevaluelegacyextendedproperty-post-singlevalueextendedproperties?view=graph-rest-1.0

Comment: Thank you Marc LaFleur. How to get the selected event Id in Outlook Calendar. Is this possible to get the selected event Id. I want to know which event is opened in outlook calendar to display the event data in Outlook Calendar Add Ins

Answer (score 2):

I created an event in Outlook calendar using Microsoft Graph API for C#.Net MVC as below.
I believe  whoever will be reading this answer has already created an app at https://apps.dev.microsoft.com and have the credentials to be used in this.

Please follow this tutorial [How to use Outlook REST APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/dotnet-tutorial) for the initial project and OAuth setup. This article also tells how to create an app as mentioned above.

Now for coding i did the following.

Create class that will hold the event properties.

```cs
public class ToOutlookCalendar
{
    public ToOutlookCalendar()
    {
        Attendees = new List<Attendee>();
    }
    [JsonProperty("subject")]
    public string Subject { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("body")]
    public Body Body { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("start")]
    public End Start { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("end")]
    public End End { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("attendees")]
    public List<Attendee> Attendees { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("location")]
    public LocationName Location { get; set; }
}

public class Attendee
{
    [JsonProperty("emailAddress")]
    public EmailAddress EmailAddress { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

public class EmailAddress
{
    [JsonProperty("address")]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Body
{
    [JsonProperty("contentType")]
    public string ContentType { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("content")]
    public string Content { get; set; }
}

public class LocationName
{
    [JsonProperty("displayName")]
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
}

public class End
{
    [JsonProperty("dateTime")]
    public string DateTime { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("timeZone")]
    public string TimeZone { get; set; }
}
```

In my controller (the controller which you would be using as mentioned in the above url for project setup) i created an action method for creating event as follows:

```cs
public async Task<ActionResult> CreateOutlookEvent()
{
    string token = await GetAccessToken();  //this will be created in the project setup url above
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
    {
        // If there's no token in the session, redirect to Home
        return Redirect("/");
    }
    using (HttpClient c = new HttpClient())
    {
        string url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events";

        //with your properties from above except for "Token"
        ToOutlookCalendar toOutlookCalendar = CreateObject();

        HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(toOutlookCalendar), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url);
        request.Content = httpContent;
        //Authentication token
        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

        var response = await c.SendAsync(request);
        var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
    return null;
}
```

CreateObject method for creating dummy event object (pardon me for naming convention but this was done only for demo purposes)

```cs
public static ToOutlookCalendar CreateObject()
{
    ToOutlookCalendar toOutlookCalendar = new ToOutlookCalendar
    {
        Subject = "Code test",
        Body = new Body
        {
            ContentType = "HTML",
            Content = "Testing outlook service"
        },
        Start = new End
        {
            DateTime = "2018-11-30T12:00:00",
            TimeZone = "Pacific Standard Time"
        },
        End = new End
        {
            DateTime = "2018-11-30T15:00:00",
            TimeZone = "Pacific Standard Time"
        },
        Location = new LocationName
        {
            DisplayName = "Harry's Bar"
        }
    };
    return toOutlookCalendar;
}
```

And i was able to create an event in outlook calendar. Some of the parts of this answer are adapted from this [THREAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51172363/post-events-to-microsoft-graph-c-sharp/51176758).

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: This helped me out. I was trying to create Event using the Graph SDK and post that to API - but was getting a 400 Bad Request. But using the above simplified class structure allowed the post to create an event successfully.