# add events to outlook calendar from flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, outlook, calendar, microsoft-graph-api

I am currently working on an app where I want to add an event to the outlook calendar when making a booking. I have searched around and I was not able to find any proper guide to help me.

My question is: how can I integrate the outlook calendar into my flutter app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MS Graph for getting this implemented, see [Create event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/calendar-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) for more information. Use this API to create a new event in a calendar. The calendar can be one for a user, or the default calendar of a Microsoft 365 group. You may find the sample code in the [Create calendar event using Microsoft Graph Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47099898/create-calendar-event-using-microsoft-graph-client) thread.